# Checkbox fade in when radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, hidden, fade

I've got a piece of code that works in Jquery 1.7.2, but it doesn't seem to work in 1.9.1.

Now I'm curious as to what changed.

Can anyone help me out?

http://jsfiddle.net/an9dV/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ikga-akkoord").hide();
$("#verzekeringen").click(function () {
    if ($("#verzekeringen").attr('checked')) {
        $("#ikga-akkoord").fadeIn();
    }


});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

http://jsfiddle.net/an9dV/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ikga-akkoord").hide();
    $(".verzekeringen").on('click', function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#ikga-akkoord").fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

You can't have multiple id's on the same page, that's why i change the id's to a class.

```
<div class="kiesbundelblokken">
<div id="belsms">
    <p>Verzekeringen</p>
    <div class="radiobuttonsverzekeringen">
        <label>
            <input class="verzekeringen" type="radio" name="verzekeringen" value="normaal"
            />ACE Toestelverzekering</label>
        <label>
            <input class="verzekeringen" type="radio" name="verzekeringen" value="plus"
            />ACE Toestelverzekering Plus</label>
        <label id="ikga-akkoord">
            <input id="akkoordvoorwaarden" type="checkbox" name="akkoordvoorwaarden"
            value="akkoordvoorwaarden" />Ik ga akkoord met deze voorwaarden</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**edit**

Based on @soyuka commment, I changed attr('checked') to .is(':checked'). A nicer and cleaner method. .attr('checked') will return undefined if something is not checked, so that's invalid.

Comment: +1 for the multiple id's but his code don't work because of the `attr('checked')`.

Comment: I know, you should just mention that you changed it :).

Comment: @soyuka oww yes true, I CHANGED IT (will change my answer).

Comment: It's all in the name
    ID = A person's Identification (ID) is unique to one person.
    Class = There are many people in a class.

Comment: Thanks alot, that fixed it. So the problem lies in the ID's and the use of attr checked?

Comment: Precies lodewijk, dat is het probleem. Wait, this should be in english. Yes, attr defines the value of the attr not if a field is checked an multiple id's will give you invalid html.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `is` instead of your `attr` :

```
$("#verzekeringen").click(function () {
    if ($("#verzekeringen").is(':checked')) {
        $("#ikga-akkoord").fadeIn();
    }


});
```

See your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/an9dV/5/).